# Double integral over a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Hi everyone: In a book I am reading, it is said the following thing: suppose $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$($m,n\geq2$), the ball $B(a,R)$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, the ball $B(b,R)$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and the ball $B((a,b),R)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$. Let $f(x,y)$ be locally integrable in $\in\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$. Then,

$$\int_{B((a,b),R)}fd\lambda_{m+n}=\int_{B(a,R)}\int_{B(b,\sqrt{R^{2}-|x-a|^{2}}}fd\lambda_{n}d\lambda_{m}.$$

Can someone explains why? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x,y)= 1_{ \{ (x,y) | (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 \le R^2 \} }(x',y') = 1_{ \{  | (x-a)^2 \le  R^2 \} }(x') 1_{ \{ y | (x'-a)^2+(y-b)^2 \le R^2 \} }(y')$.

Note carefully the $x'$ in the rightmost characteristic function set.

Now use Fubini on $g \cdot f$.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you. Do you know any references that treats double integrals in balls of R m+n?

Comment: I know none that deal explicitly with integrals of this form...

Answer (score 2):

Think of elements of $\mathbb R^{m+n}$ as ordered pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in\mathbb R^m$ and $y\in\mathbb R^n$; these two are orthogonal subspaces of  $\mathbb R^{m+n}$.  This is what the notation $(a,b)$ refers to, by the way.

The distance between $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$ is $\sqrt{|x-a|^2+|y-b|^2}$,  due to orthogonality of the two subspaces. Therefore, the ball $B((a,b),R)$ can be written as $$\{(x,y) : |x-a|^2+|y-b|^2 <R^2 \}\tag1$$
(or $\le R^2$ if it's closed, does not matter for integration). For the purpose of integration, the inequality in  (1) is arranged as $|y-b|<\sqrt{R^2-|x-a|^2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you. Do you know any book that traits double integral over balls of R m+n?